# Stereographic Projection of circle of Complex plane to Sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, circles, plane-curves, stereographic-projections

Source :  Complex Variables by  Ablowitz and Fokas

Q : Show that a circle in the z- plane corresponds to a circle on the sphere.

Sphere : $X^2+Y^2+(Z-1)^2=1$

Attempt : 
x,y are in z-plane (complex)

Transformations Used $X=\frac{4x}{x^2+y^2+4},Y=\frac{4y}{x^2+y^2+4},Z=\frac{2(x^2+y^2)}{|z|^2+4}$

$x=\frac{2X}{2-Z},y=\frac{2Y}{2-Z}$

Let the equation of circle on z-plane be $A(x^2+y^2)+Bx+Cy+D=0$

After substituting x,y in above equation and using Equation of sphere.
I got

$2BX+2CY+Z(A-D)+2D=0$

This is equation of plane; why I am not able to get equation of circle?

Where's my mistake ?

Comment: In 3D, the intersection between a plane and a sphere *is* a circle.

Comment: I wrote general equation of circle, means if $A=0$  even straight line will give equation of circle. But, this may not be the case when line passes through North Pole ?